# What is the most up to date design template I should use?

Tags: website-design, template-design, responsive-design

I am a web-developer and am starting a new project. First step is designing the site. In the past, I have used [960 grid system](http://960.gs/) but I was wondering if this is still the standard pretty much? Is there something better now that suits the responsive craze?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well there is now [978.gs](http://978.gs/) that is better than 960.  That said there is no reason to use 978.gs or 960 but since the OP asked for a web design template other than 960 I provided the solution of 978.gs. You ask for a design template when you should be designing in the browser if you're using Bootstrap. If you use 978.gs you will need to build your own CSS which defeats the purpose of Bootstrap.

If you are going to target responsive I would suggest looking into [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) and start learning how to design in the browser.

[Google search for designing in the browser.](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=designing%20in%20the%20browser)

Also, not to be rude, the 1st step isn't "designing", you are missing a few steps:

- Purpose and goals
- content strategy
- sketch/mockup
- wireframe

Comment: I am actually using bootstrap! is 978 more pertinent to responsive?

Comment: 978.gs does not mention being responsive.  Their site is not responsive either.

Comment: I love **Foundation**.

Comment: @Scott is very liberal that way...